# HTMLUnit Many Error in Basic Example

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to get a basic example working using HTMLUnit.

I am trying to get this code to search for a drill on the homedepot website:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {



        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.homedepot.ca");

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("search_terms_form");

        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Go");
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("q");

        // Change the value of the text field
        textField.setValueAttribute("drill");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button 
        button.click();




        System.out.println(page1.getTitleText());
    }
```

Judging by the error messages, it appears my code for the button and the textfield are incorrect. I've tried some variations of getting by name, ID, and value but am not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Any comments/feedback is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's the error code. When I comment out the button and textfield initializations, the error goes away.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[Go]
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByValue(HtmlForm.java:795)
at HDSearch.main(HDSearch.java:30)
```

Comment: Please post the error messages! It's pretty much impossible to know what triggered a particular error when you can't see what the error is!

Comment: @EdCottrell Thx Ed. Error message posted.

Comment: It seems like that page doesn't have an `<input>` element with the value `Go`. I'm on a mobile device and can't currently check the HTML source, but you might start by doing that.

Comment: @EdCottrell The Search button doesn't have any ID or Name associated with it. All it has is <button class="search-button" type="submit"><span>
        Go</span>
    </button>

Comment: Well, that is a `<button>` with HTML content that is a `<span>` with HTML content `Go`. Your code, however, looks for an `<input>` with *value* `Go`. Those aren't the same thing at all, which is why you're getting an error message.

Comment: @EdCottrell Good point. I was hoping that getting by value would pick up the value from the span. I've always thought that buttons were supposed to have ids or names associated with them. Trying to figure out if there's something I can do with that class value.

Comment: Try `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ed hinted about the reason. If you still need help, you can use the below to get the Button with a given class name:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.homedepot.ca");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("search_terms_form");

    final HtmlElement button = form.getFirstByXPath("//button[@class='search-button']");
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("q");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("drill");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button 
    button.click();
    System.out.println(page1.getTitleText());
}
```

}